# Laravel Redis creates two databases

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm using Redis for queues and for caching. My config file:

```
'default' => [
  'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
],

'cache' => [
  'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
],
```

And in my ENV file I have

```
REDIS_DB=6
REDIS_CACHE_DB=7
```

After updating these I always run `php artisan config:cache`.

The Cache DB value is correctly picked up, however the `REDIS_DB` value is not. If I delete all my databases and then reload a page, the session is always stored in db3. I think I previously had it set to 3, but I can't find any other place where this is defined. I also see that old values show up in db3 (I can see they're old because they use an old prefix), so probably there's something still in the memory? I'm running all of this locally.

**Update**

I just noticed that my cache items are stored in both databases... No idea why but it's probably related to the above?

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart Redis in order for the changes to take effect. It still had the old DB and values stored in memory.